# How to efficiently add simple symbols for repeated use

Tags: symbols

I wish to use custom symbols in my math boxes. They are very simple symbols, but I use them very often in my LaTeX document (so far, I've used them at least 150 times). I have managed to put them in the document by defining a new command using `\includegraphics` to import a 2KB PDF of them I saved using `Tikz`, but when I call this command 150 times, the file is way too slow to compile.

The symbols are simple, though I need the freedom to place more math around them, as follows (by the way, I wonder if there is a way to not make `b` droop like that):

[image]

Each letter there is a parameter.

As can be seen, the symbols themselves are very simple, three lines at most. I cannot believe that there isn't a faster way to compile them. I have written them into Tikz as follows (this example is of an X which isn't in the image above):

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}%
    \draw (-1ex,-2ex) -- (1ex,2ex);%
    \draw (-1ex,2ex) -- (1ex,-2ex);%
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

I saved this as a PDF, which ended up having 2KB in size, and imported it into my main `.tex` file using (this example is of the K):

```
\newcommand{\knot}[6][1]{%
\prescript{#4}{#2}{\vcenter{\hbox{
\includegraphics[page=1, scale = #1]{K-notation/knot.pdf}
\newcommand{\starcup}{$\sqcup$\kern-0.58em{$\star$}}
}}^{#5}_{#3}} #6
}

% Then, inside math text (after \begin{document}, of course):
\knot{\Omega}{\boldsymbol{\eta\cdot}}{a}{b}{c}
```

I have found many ways to import such a custom character into LaTeX with this forum, but none of them proved to be any faster. Even though this is already much faster than drawing the symbols using `Tikz` every time, it still takes too long for such a simple symbol.

Comment: you could store the tikz picture or the part with the graphics in a box (see \newsavebox and \sbox) and then reuse the box as often your want.

Comment: That works very well! It compiles a lot faster now, but I now I don't know how to adjust the symbol size... (sometimes, such as in footnotes or exponents, it's better if it is smaller) Is there a way to do this?

Comment: well how many sizes do you need? 3 or 4? so make four boxes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are macros that (I think) do what you want. Each symbol is a `tikzpicture` that is stored in an `\sbox` so it won't be redrawn each time it's called. Then it's turned into an operator so the `\sideset` command (`amsmath`) will work to place the sub- and superscripts. The `scalerel` package is used to scale and position the symbols just like `\sum`.

Two global parameters can be adjusted to your liking. First, `\symscale` will affect line thickness in the symbols: larger numbers produce thinner lines. Second, `\trimlen` controls the horizontal spacing between the symbols and their scripts.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz, scalerel, amsmath}

\newcommand{\symscale}{.25}
\newcommand{\trimlen}{1pt}

\newsavebox{\Kforward}
\sbox{\Kforward}{\tikz[scale=\symscale, trim left=-\trimlen, trim right=\symscale cm+\trimlen]
    {\draw(0,0)--(0,2)(1,2)--(0,1)--(1,0);}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\KSYM}{\scalerel*{\usebox{\Kforward}}{\sum}}
\newcommand{\Ksym}[4]{\sideset{^{#3}_{#1}}{^{#4}_{#2}}\KSYM}

\newsavebox{\Kbackward}
\sbox{\Kbackward}{\tikz[scale=\symscale, trim left=-\trimlen, trim right=\symscale cm+\trimlen]
    {\draw(1,0)--(1,2)(0,2)--(1,1)--(0,0);}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\KBSYM}{\scalerel*{\usebox{\Kbackward}}{\sum}}
\newcommand{\Kbsym}[4]{\sideset{^{#3}_{#1}}{^{#4}_{#2}}\KBSYM}

\newsavebox{\Lforward}
\sbox{\Lforward}{\tikz[scale=\symscale, trim left=-\trimlen, trim right=\symscale cm+\trimlen]
    {\draw(0,2)--(1,0)(0,0)--(.5,1);}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\LSYM}{\scalerel*{\usebox{\Lforward}}{\sum}}
\newcommand{\Lsym}[3]{\sideset{^{#3}_{#1}}{_{#2}}\LSYM}

\newsavebox{\Lbackward}
\sbox{\Lbackward}{\tikz[scale=\symscale, trim left=-\trimlen, trim right=\symscale cm+\trimlen]
    {\draw(1,2)--(0,0)(1,0)--(.5,1);}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\LBSYM}{\scalerel*{\usebox{\Lbackward}}{\sum}}
\newcommand{\Lbsym}[3]{\sideset{_{#1}}{^{#3}_{#2}}\LBSYM}

\newsavebox{\Xsymbol}
\sbox{\Xsymbol}{\tikz[scale=\symscale, trim left=-\trimlen, trim right=\symscale cm+\trimlen]
    {\draw(0,0)--(1,2)(0,2)--(1,0);}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\XSYM}{\scalerel*{\usebox{\Xsymbol}}{\sum}}
\newcommand{\Xsym}[4]{\sideset{^{#3}_{#1}}{^{#4}_{#2}}\XSYM}

\begin{document}

\[
\Ksym{\Omega}{\boldsymbol{\eta\cdot}}{\,a}{b}c\qquad
d\Kbsym{\Omega}{\boldsymbol{\eta\cdot}}{\,a}{b}\qquad
d\Lsym{\Omega}{\boldsymbol{\eta\cdot}}{\,a}c\qquad
d\Lbsym{\Omega}{\boldsymbol{\eta\cdot}}{b}c\qquad
d\Xsym{\Omega}{\boldsymbol{\eta\cdot}}{\,a}{b}c
\]

\end{document}
```